# Converting ARGB to RGB in java

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm trying some algorithms to write a method to remove alpha value from a color and give its identical rgb values but seems my test is always failing. I belive it is called alpha blending? I'm not sure. This is the algorithm I use for converting.

```
public static int removeAlpha(int foreground, int background) {
        int redForeground = Color.red(foreground);
        int redBackground = Color.red(background);
        int greenForeground = Color.green(foreground);
        int greenBackground = Color.green(background);
        int blueForeground = Color.blue(foreground);
        int blueBackground = Color.blue(background);
        int alphaForeground = Color.alpha(foreground);
        int redNew = (redForeground * alphaForeground) + (redBackground * (1 - alphaForeground));
        int greenNew = (greenForeground * alphaForeground) + (greenBackground * (1 - alphaForeground));
        int blueNew = (blueForeground * alphaForeground) + (blueBackground * (1 - alphaForeground));
        return Color.rgb(redNew, greenNew, blueNew);
    }
```

And the test like this

```
@Test
    public void removeAlpha() {
        int red = Color.RED;
        Assert.assertEquals(0xFFFF7F7F, Heatmap.removeAlpha(red, 0xFFFFFFFF));
    }

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :-32897
Actual   :-258
```

when i draw red in photoshop and set the opacity to 50%, it gives me 255,127,127 rgb which seems identical to 50% opaque pure red. I think there the algorithm is false. Any helps would be appreciated.

Edit: Here are the mock Color:

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(Color.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Color.rgb(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                int red = (int) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                int green = (int) invocation.getArguments()[1];
                int blue = (int) invocation.getArguments()[2];
                return (0xFF << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
            }
        });
        PowerMockito.when(Color.alpha(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return ((int)invocation.getArguments()[0])>>>24;
            }
        });
        PowerMockito.when(Color.red(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return (((int)invocation.getArguments()[0])>>16) & 0xFF;
            }
        });
        PowerMockito.when(Color.green(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return (((int)invocation.getArguments()[0])>>8) & 0XFF;
            }
        });
        PowerMockito.when(Color.blue(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return (int)invocation.getArguments()[0] & 0xFF;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that I mocked the Color static class but it's not that important. I just mocked them because junit would not let me without mocking them. I just used the source code of them so they are working fine.

Comment: Your formular seems to be correct. What i recognised however is that you are ignoring `alphaBackground`. It's not the problem here though, since your testcase sets this property to 100%.

Comment: You're treating your color values like a range between `[0, 1]`. Is it possible that your `Color.xx` functions are returning values of `[0, 255]`?

Comment: @maja Yes that's because I assume that background color will always full opaque not to complicate things.

Comment: Try to replace the `1-` in your formula with `255-`

Comment: @maja that's not enough (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your formula treats `1` as 100%, but your Color functions are returning / expecting values in the range of `[0, 255]`, which means that `255 = 100%`.

You have to use the following formula:

`newColor = (colorA * opacityA + colorB * (255 - opacityA)) / 255`

**Example:**

```
foreground = 256
background = 0
foreground-alpha = 25%
```

In the range of `[0,255]`, 25% are equal to 63. T
he result of this example should be 63 since `foreground * 25% + background * 75%` is `63`.

So in order to get the 75%, you need `100% - 25% = 256 - 63 = 193`

**Second problem:**

Your test case is wrong. You are taking `100% red` + `100% white` which should result in 100% red, not `0xFFFF7F7F`.

As @frarugi87 said in his answer, you first have to set red's alpha channel to 50%.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes you are right, I changed it but the test is still failing. I will try to reformulate it and try again. Thanks

Comment: This is not true, since a 255 opacity leads to an increase in colorA. The correct formula would be `(colorA * opacityA + colorB * (255 - opacityA))/255`, but in my opinion my solution (converting the alpha channel in 0-1) is better

Comment: Well seems the formula is the same. But the results are still off. Expected :-32897
Actual   :-16711680

Comment: The important thing is to use the same range - either [0, 1] or [0, 255]. Using [0,1] is definitly simpler, but it requires lots of conversions that are not neccessary.

Comment: You can use the [0,255] range for colors but you should use the [0,1] range for alpha (1 division), otherwise you have to divide all the components by 255 (3 divisions)

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu did you get -16711680 as a result using this code or the code in my answer?

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu Your test case is wrong. I updated my answer

Comment: Yes I updated my testcase as this Assert.assertEquals(0xFFFF7F7F, Heatmap.removeAlpha(0x7FFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF));

Comment: Ok, and did my answer or maja's one with my edit work? They should both work. If not, what is the output of both of them? BTW I think that instead of 0x7FF... you should put 0x80F.... but you will see it in the output (if the values are close, you'll notice it... rounding issues are easy to be spotted)

Comment: I edited my code according to your helps and the test results as well. But for some reason the test is still failing

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu NO, do not edit your original question in response to already given answers. This should not be done on SE sites. Instead, use comments or and "Edit"-block in your question to add additional information.

Comment: As I already said, you should either use my code (where alphaChannel is a `double` and is `Color.alpha() / 255`) or use maja's code BUT you will have to divide every result color by 255. Moreover I suggest you to ADD edits to your question, not to modify the question itself, otherwise the answers would reply to previous questions and... everything becomes a mess

Comment: As you said, I changed the test value to 0x80FF0000 but the value is not that much of a difference. I don't expect the test to pass until i give it some precision fallback. It should be fine if its closer to the expected value.

Comment: @maja Sorry about editing. It's just that writing the code block here will be unreadable so I preferred to edit it.

Comment: Sorry about editing the answer again. I think it is working now. Thanks for all your great helps :)

Comment: Ok then tell us what you used and, if it was one of these answers, please mark it as accepted...

Comment: I rolled back the question to the original version. Glad we could help, but don't forget to decide which of our answer you wanna upvote - they are roughly the same, but @frarugi87 found the assert-bug earlier.

Comment: (@maja just add the `/255` - or `/256` - in the formula, for completeness sake) ;)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I'm not really into java, so I can be wrong. I'm just using common programming notions, so some tweakings can be needed.

I think you are messing with data types... You are getting the integer representation of your color, i.e. 0-255, and multiplying it as if it was a 0-1 representation. Try this:

```
double alphaForeground = ((double)Color.alpha(foreground)) / 255.0;
int redNew = ((int)round((redForeground * alphaForeground) + (redBackground * (1 - alphaForeground))));
int greenNew = ((int)round((greenForeground * alphaForeground) + (greenBackground * (1 - alphaForeground))));
int blueNew = ((int)round((blueForeground * alphaForeground) + (blueBackground * (1 - alphaForeground))));
```

There can be rounding issues, but... this should work.

Just another remark: `Color.RED` has a 255 alpha channel. This means that `removeAlpha(red, 0xFFFFFFFF)` returns red itself, not 0xFFFF7F7F. In order to get that value you should write

```
int red = Color.RED;
red.alpha = 0x80;
```

(or some close value)

Comment: I think that in this case 255 is better, since with 256 you will never have a 100% opacity... However, 255 vs 256 is less than 0.4% of error ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 118, 118, 188);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I'm trying to do is to get the rgb value of a color with alpha, meaning make it full opaque with different red, green and blue values.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu, sorry... I just see at function name `removeAlpha`, and as I know this is correct way to remove alpha

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu To remove the alpha, as Alexander correctly showed, simply pull its value to the maximum opacity (255)

Comment: No its not the same.. 128,R,G,B != R,G,B since 50% alpha will change the color completely. That is why the assertion failing. I said you need to remove the alpha but keep the color identical, something called alpha blending.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu Nobody talked about `128,R,G,B`. We said: `255,R,G,B`.

Comment: Yes that's the wrong thing about the answer. The question was to remove the alpha and get an identical color. When you have a color 128,R,G,B and remove it like you did completely which makes it 255,R,G,B gives you a whole different visual color. What I asked was to get the visually identical color. Check the answers.